# Unable to produce consume messages

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to spring-integration kafka. I am setting up kafka on docker but unable to produce and consume messages. Here is my docker compose file 
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

```
zookeeper:
        image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
        ports:
         - "2181:2181"

kafka:
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        ports:
           - "9092:9092"
           - "9999:9999"
        environment:
           - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=20.0.201.75
           - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9090,OUTSIDE://:9092
           - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9090,OUTSIDE://20.0.201.75:9092
           - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
           - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
           - JMX_PORT=9999
           - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE
           - KAFKA_JMX_OPTS= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=kafka -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999
        volumes:
           - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I am poducing messages to 20.0.201.75:9092 and consuming messages from 20.0.201.75:9092 and 20.0.201.75 is the dockerhostip here.Producer side code is

```
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;


    public String sendData() {
        System.out.println("hewe");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> s = kafkaTemplate.send("dms", Integer.valueOf(0),String.valueOf(i+230), "added message in dms");
            try {
                s.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sent successfully");

        return "";

    }
```

Consumer side code is:

```
    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() throws Exception {
        ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties("dms");
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String,String> kmlc = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String,String>(consumerFactory(), properties);
        // set more properties
        return kmlc;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "20.0.201.75:9092");
        // set more properties
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what address you are trying to produce/consume from... Or what error you are getting

Comment: @cricket_007 20.0.201.75 is the docke host ip to which I am producing and consuming messages

Comment: Is the code running on the same machine as the container? If not, are firewalls allowing port 9092 traffic?

Comment: firewall is not running on my server @cricket_007

Comment: How about the first question - where is your code running relative to the container?

Comment: My code is running on my local machine

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to set `OUTSIDE://localhost:9092`, then?

Comment: You might be sending the data before the listener has fully started. Set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`. It defaults to `latest`.

Comment: I have run a new docker image and now everything is working fine. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: just run this command   docker run -d -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 9081-9083:8081-8083 -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=20.0.168.37 -e RUNNING_SAMPLEDATA=1 lensesio/fast-data-dev and zookeper, kafka and console are setup